# How can I install packages on my heroku app?

Tags: python, heroku, virtualenv, pyramid, uuid

I have an app that makes use of shortuuid (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/shortuuid/0.1) that is working fine locally when I run it with runapp.py:

```
import os

from paste.deploy import loadapp
from waitress import serve

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    app = loadapp('config:production.ini', relative_to='.')

    serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

It does not work, however, when I try and run it with ../bin/pserve development.ini. I get the error: import error: no module named shortuuid. When I push it to heroku I get the same error. I have installed shortuuid into my virtual environment where my app is run and can only conclude that the absence of this installation on heroku is whats causing the problem.

I have tried replacing the development.ini code with the production.ini code and it still does not work so I assume its something else (maybe the import os line on runapp.py?)

Comment: DO you mean you have the problem locally too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually create a `requirements.txt` file that contains the packages:

```
Flask==0.9
Jinja2==2.6
Werkzeug==0.8.3
distribute==0.6.27
wsgiref==0.1.2

Flask-Cache==0.10.0

gunicorn==0.17.2
```

You can create that file with `pip`:

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Comment: Yep. Heroku installs those packages.

Comment: I installed a specific version of torch using ```--find-links``` flag. Entire command was ```pip install torch==1.3.1+cpu -f <URL>```. I did ```pip freeze > requirements.txt``` But the build fails because it is not able to install ```torch==1.3.1+cpu``` What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Place a `requirements.txt` in the root directory of your git repo, with your required dependencies (specified in pip/easy-install format).

Example taken from the [Heroku website](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip):

```
Flask==0.8
Jinja2==2.6
Werkzeug==0.8.3
certifi==0.0.8
chardet==1.0.1
distribute==0.6.24
gunicorn==0.14.2
requests==0.11.1
```